# Javascript API: queryTask error - where should I put the alert?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Where in the code do I add an error message if nothing is returned?

```
     function execute() {
     //
     var queryTask = new QueryTask("http://sepa-app-gis01/arcgis/rest/services/live/SEARCH/MapServer/2");
     var query = new Query();
     query.returnGeometry = true;
     query.outFields = [
       "POSTCODE"
     ];
     query.text = dom.byId("Postcode").value.toUpperCase();
     queryTask.execute(query, showResults);
 };
```

Should I add Error to the queryTask.execute first??

```
queryTask.execute(query, showResults, Error)
```

Answer (score 4):

The Error function will returns a result if something is wrong with the query, like an improperly formatted where statement or a incorrect URL. A result of no records found isn't an error. In your showResults function, you can test to see if any results were returned, like this:

```
function showResults(results){
    if (results.features.length === 0) {
        console.log("No features found.");
    } else {
        'do something
    }
});
```